# How to display multiple notifications on different days?

Tags: android

I need help and I am a novice regarding notifications and alarms managers on different days and different notifications for example:

I have 2 calendars already defined

calendar.set (2020,5,15,0,0,0);
notificationManager.notify(0, NotifyBuilder.build());
This is showing the notification "We remind you that you can request a process now"

calendar.set (2020,5,20,0,0,0);
notificationManager.notify(1, NotifyBuilder1.build());
This is showing the notification "We remind you that you can request a process that ends in 10 days"

This code is of MainActivity()

```java
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2020,5,15,0,0,0);

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.set(2020,5,20,0,0,0);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1,intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am1 = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
am1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```

This code is a class AlarmReceiver()

```java
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int id = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("We remind you that you can request a process now").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})

        notificationManager.notify(id, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        Log.i("TEST", "Count: "+id);

        long when2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager2 = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
                notificationIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound2 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("We remind you that you can request a process that ends in 10 days").setSound(alarmSound2)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when2)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent2)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager2.notify(++id, mNotifyBuilder2.build());
        Log.i("TEST", "Count: "+id);
        }
    }
```

BUT IN THE NOTIFICATION OF THE DATE 06/15/2020 I GET THE TWO NOTIFICATIONS AT THE SAME TIME AND IN THE SAME WAY OF THE OTHER DATE 06/20/2020

The "id" is correctly of for .notify() but i dont now problem

Comment: Basically, your `AlarmReceiver` should be posting only one `Notification`. It's going to be called once for each alarm you've set, so if you have two `Notification`s there, you're going to get two each time it fires.

Comment: I understand Mike M, so AlarmReceiver only receives a notification, could it be done as an if or other condition that could show different notifications on each date? What do you recommend me to do or do you have any ideas with a code example? Thanks for answering

Comment: Normally, something like that would be handled by passing different data on the `Intent`s used to create the alarms. For example, in `MainActivity`, right after the `Intent intent = new Intent(...);` line, you could do something like `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "We remind you that you can request a process now");`. Then, in `onReceive()`, you could retrieve that like `String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);`, and use `text` in the `setContentText()` call. For `intent2`, you would do the same thing, except with its `"...10 days"` text. Follow me?

Comment: @MikeM. I did what I mentioned but in the notification the one from the `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "We remind you that you can request a process now");`

Comment: The notification of the first attempt is repeated once more

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you mean. Are you saying that the second `Notification` is showing at the correct time, but its text is wrong? Are you sure you didn't get the `Intent`s mixed up somewhere? Anyhoo, these are the changes to your code that I was describing above, just to be clear: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10mexCQ7y9G2XSnw68PnUUgY_t6lvB2yJ/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much, the mistake I was making is the explanation you gave me of the Notification, that is, I was calling the same notification twice, sorry for the inconvenience @Mike M

Comment: No worries. Is everything working now?

Comment: Everything correctly, thanks .. how do I follow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike M's comment the solution is:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2020,5,15,0,0,0);
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.set(2020,5,20,0,0,0);

 

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "We remind you that you can request a process now");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "We remind you that you can request a process thats end in 10 days");
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1,intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am1 = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```

Class ALarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

int id = 0;
String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText(text)
.setSound(alarmSound)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})

notificationManager.notify(id, mNotifyBuilder.build());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are creating two notifications in your `onReceive()`-method regardless of which intent triggered the broadcast.

You need to check which intent triggered the broadcast (this is the `Intent` parameter in `onReceive()`) and then send an appropriate notification.

You could do this, for example, by initialising your `intent` and `intent2` in `MainActivity` with unique actions (for example, `Intent intent = "new Intent("com.myapp.ALARM1")`) and then checking in `onReceive()` for the actions and acting based on them. Note, that this would require you to set up intent-filters for your actions in your manifest file.

So in your `onReceive()` you might have something like this:

```java
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.myapp.MY_ALARM1")) {
            // notification here
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.myapp.MY_ALARM2")) {
            // other notification here
        }
```

Comment: Didn't notice the comments the question got while I was writing this answer, my answer is quite similar to them.